# How to get free wallpapers which i can use for my developed Application in Android?

Tags: android, wallpaper

I am developing one Application where i need some images which i am going to use as background. This images should look like the wallpaper of the phone. Basically I will set this images as the wallpaper of the Launcher Screen with some clock. How to get this wallpaper from the web??

How people are using the different wallpapers for the Widget Applications??

Thanks.